# Primefaces how to sort the year dropdownlist p:calendar component

Tags: javascript, sorting, primefaces

Does the p:calendar component in Primefaces support sorting the year dropdownlist? By default, it is sorted by ascending, but how about if I want to sort it by descending? I've tried to implement it by using javascript but unfortunately the sort was gone after I selected an option in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Please show your relevant code

Comment: Look at the javascript source in github. It might contain an easy to override function (or even a non-visible parameter)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yearrange` attribute. But you need to change/override something to make it works.
I see Primefaces calendar which is using datepicker and datepicker just support yearrange ascending. So I think you can do like that.

```
 <p:calendar yearrange="2027:2017"... />
```

And override something that datapicker can support new yearrange, like (just my short sample)

```
$.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader = function(inst, drawMonth, drawYear, minDate, maxDate,
secondary, monthNames, monthNamesShort) {

var inMinYear, inMaxYear, month, years, thisYear, determineYear, year, endYear,
    changeMonth = this._get(inst, "changeMonth"),
    changeYear = this._get(inst, "changeYear"),
    showMonthAfterYear = this._get(inst, "showMonthAfterYear"),
    html = "<div class='ui-datepicker-title'>",
    monthHtml = "";

// month selection
if (secondary || !changeMonth) {
    monthHtml += "<span class='ui-datepicker-month'>" + monthNames[drawMonth] + "</span>";
} else {
    inMinYear = (minDate && minDate.getFullYear() === drawYear);
    inMaxYear = (maxDate && maxDate.getFullYear() === drawYear);
    monthHtml += "<select class='ui-datepicker-month' data-handler='selectMonth' data-event='change'>";
    for (month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
        if ((!inMinYear || month >= minDate.getMonth()) && (!inMaxYear || month <= maxDate.getMonth())) {
            monthHtml += "<option value='" + month + "'" +
                (month === drawMonth ? " selected='selected'" : "") +
                ">" + monthNamesShort[month] + "</option>";
        }
    }
    monthHtml += "</select>";
}

if (!showMonthAfterYear) {
    html += monthHtml + (secondary || !(changeMonth && changeYear) ? "&#xa0;" : "");
}

// year selection
if (!inst.yearshtml) {
    inst.yearshtml = "";
    if (secondary || !changeYear) {
        html += "<span class='ui-datepicker-year'>" + drawYear + "</span>";
    } else {
        // determine range of years to display
        years = this._get(inst, "yearRange").split(":");
        thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        determineYear = function(value) {
            var year = (value.match(/c[+\-].*/) ? drawYear + parseInt(value.substring(1), 10) :
                (value.match(/[+\-].*/) ? thisYear + parseInt(value, 10) :
                    parseInt(value, 10)));
            return (isNaN(year) ? thisYear : year);
        };
        year = determineYear(years[0]);
        endYear = Math.max(year, determineYear(years[1] || ""));
        year = (minDate ? Math.max(year, minDate.getFullYear()) : year);
        endYear = (maxDate ? Math.min(endYear, maxDate.getFullYear()) : endYear);
        inst.yearshtml += "<select class='ui-datepicker-year' data-handler='selectYear' data-event='change'>";

        var startYear = determineYear(years[0]);
        var absoluteEndYear = determineYear(years[1]);

        if (startYear <= absoluteEndYear) {
            for (; year <= endYear; year++) {
                inst.yearshtml += "<option value='" + year + "'" +
                    (year === drawYear ? " selected='selected'" : "") +
                    ">" + year + "</option>";
            }
        } else {
            for (; startYear >= absoluteEndYear; startYear--) {
                inst.yearshtml += "<option value='" + startYear + "'" +
                    (startYear === drawYear ? " selected='selected'" : "") +
                    ">" + startYear + "</option>";
            }
        }
        inst.yearshtml += "</select>";

        html += inst.yearshtml;
        inst.yearshtml = null;
    }
}

html += this._get(inst, "yearSuffix");
if (showMonthAfterYear) {
    html += (secondary || !(changeMonth && changeYear) ? "&#xa0;" : "") + monthHtml;
}
html += "</div>";
return html;}
```

Or you can write or extends more p:calendar component.

Hope that helps.